# grouping collection of item by interface implementation

Tags: c#, linq, generics, collections

I have a collection of object that all have a common base type. These object are derived at many different level and all properties come from interfaces implementation.

```
// my list of all the items i have (Item being the base class)
var items = new List<Item>();
```

Now i need to group those item by interfaces they implement but each class implement multiple interfaces.

To get all my interfaces i use the Assembly reflection like so :

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(o => o.IsInterface).ToList();
```

This is very cute but the problem is that i get a list of `Type` object so i cannot easily iterate and use Linq to query the items for each type and retrieve the collection grouped. I know i have to build the collection manually i was hoping to use a `OfType<>` but i can't with a `Type`.

here what i was hoping it to look like in the final :

```
// my list of all the items i have (Item being the base class)
var items = new List<Item>();

// get all interface of my assembly
var interfaces = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(o => o.IsInterface).ToList();

// create an anonymous group with type and list of items of that type
var groups = interfaces.Select(interfaceType=> 
    new 
        { 
            Type = interfaceType, 
            Items = items.OfType<interfaceType>().ToList() // here's my issue
        });
```

I am wondering if there is something i have overlooked and didn't see or do i really have to compare items by item to see if they implement the type. Or my second solution is using a `items.Where(item => items as [My Type]).Where(item=> item != null)` which is not much cleaner.

Edit :
here's a sample of data that might help

```
inputs (3 classes) : 

item 1 : ISquare, IRectangle, IData
item 2 : IRectangle, IData, IReporting
item 3 : IData

Desired output (collection of 4 because 4 interface exists) :

{ ISquare, { item 1 }},
{ IRectangle, { item 1, item 2 }},
{ IData, { item 1, item 2, item 3 }},
{ IReporting, { item 2, item 3 }}
```

Comment: Why not use reflection to get the interfaces that the current object implements using `GetType().FindInterfaces()`.  Though its not really obvious on exactly how you want to group them once you have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `interfaceType` is an object of type `System.Type`, the variable cannot be used as a type parameter of `OfType<T>()` method.

You can use [`IsAssignableFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx) with `Where`, like this:

```
var groups = interfaces.Select(interfaceType => new { 
    Type = interfaceType
,   Items = items.Where(item => interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(item.GetType()).ToList()
});
```

Comment: Much more readable than checking for `is` as one of my other options. This is perfect.